# S3 static website hosting, which DNS CNAME record should I use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have created a S3 static website e.g. www.example.com

The S3 endpoind is: www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

When I dig this DNS

```
www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 55 IN CNAME s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 55 IN A x.x.x.x
```

So should I set a CNAME record to "s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" instead of "www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"?

Comment: I'd address this with the amazon folks who can give you the definitive answer and rationale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the website endpoint CNAME target shown in the console when viewing your bucket, and disregard the rest of the implementation details.

The mechanism that AWS uses to ultimately resolve that name so you can route traffic to their servers is something you should consider opaque.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

If your DNS is hosted in Route 53, use an Alias A record, instead of a CNAME.